# rsync : how to replace only newer files on the target

Tags: reverse, rsync, updating

How can I use *rsync* to restore a backup system to the current system.
Files, which are newer on the target should be replaced by the older ones, and files on the target which don't exist in the source (backup) should be deleted.
Restoring a backup version without copying everything is a common task, isn't it?
I want *rsync* just the opposite of its standard action. I haven't found suitable options for *rsync* or do I have to use a different tool?
Thanks for any hints, Helmut